# Apache Tomcat virtual directories. Redirects to wrong location. ColdFusion Lucee

Tags: apache, tomcat, lucee

I am trying to get a local version of Lucee ColdFusion running my app - which resides as two directories... the main app, and the client custom code.
To that myDomain.com should pull from the 'site' and myDomain.com/app/ should pull from the app.

I can be logged in to my site, and pulling data via includes etc, but if I try to browse (or make a call to) /app/cfc/myCFC.cfc ...
the behavior redirects to the 'root' and logs my app out.

my server XML looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" >

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"  SSLEngine="on" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" /> 

    <Service name="Catalina" >

        <Connector port="8888" 
                    protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                    connectionTimeout="20000"
                    redirectPort="8443" />

        <Connector port="8009" 
                    protocol="AJP/1.3" 
                    redirectPort="8443" />

        <Engine name="Catalina" 
                defaultHost="127.0.0.1" >

            <Host name="local.dev.myDomain.com" appBase="webapps" >
                <Context path="/" docBase="C:\wwwroot\site" />
                <Context path="/app" docBase="C:\wwwroot\app" />
            </Host>

        </Engine>

    </Service>

</Server>
```

If it helps to understand; this is a legacy app running in production on Windows, Apache 2.2 and ColdFusion 11. I have the app aliased in Apache 2.2 like this:

```
Alias /app/ C:/wwwroot/app
```

I am trying to evaluate Lucee to see if our app will work on that platform without too many changes.

One noticeable difference, due to using the built in webserver, is the port 8888
so the actual url looks like: mydomain.com:8888/app/cfc
I do not know if this is the problem or something else. If I cannot find a solution, I'll install Apache 2.2 and match the config

Any help is greatly appreciated - jp

NOTE: I just changed the host in this txt to accurately mimic my setup - if that makes a difference.
local.dev.myDomain.com (only the 'myDomain' is specifically my domain, not literally myDomain)

Comment: Have you added a Lucee mapping? In the Lucee server or web administrator, go to "Archives & Resources" -> "Mappings". I would remove the Tomcat server.xml mapping and make Lucee do it instead. A request for a .cfc to Tomcat should be sent to the Lucee servlet properly and Lucee should be able to take it from there.

Comment: I DO have a mapping in lucee.

Comment: With this: "the behavior redirects to the 'root' and logs my app out."... is your app getting hit then?

Comment: @jordan, yes, its the strangest thing, I can see in the network output that the cfc is called, a Status Code:302 is returned, and it redirects to the index of the app, with the session cleared, prompting me to log in. Its a little like CFC explorer behavior - when you browse to a cfc w/o a method passed - and it shoves you off the CFAdmin cfc inspector... but that's silly as this is Lucee not adobe, no reason to assume that behavior.

Comment: Is your app behind SSL/TLS? Is the redirect happening because you are requesting over port 80 (well 8888) non-secure and it is trying to get the request over port 443 (8443)?

Comment: @muguel - good suggestion, there was a piece of code i had to tweak in my application onrequeststart, that accommodate no-ssl on local and was being thrown off by the :8888 in the remote_addr - HOWEVER the behavior persists just as before - so the issue lies somewhere else, I'll keep looking